# How do I run a bash script in a server with `for` and `R` code that I can exit the terminal and does not kill the process?

Tags: r, bash, ubuntu, server

Context: I am running a simulation via R that each repetition takes too long and it is memory consuming. Therefore, I need that for every repetition another session in R starts, so that I will not run into memory issues.

My problem: After executing my bash script, I `exit` from the terminal, the current repetition finishes successfully, but the next one does not start (I am running it on a server via `ssh`).

What I have done:

`compoisson.sh` bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for rho in $(seq 1 3); do
    for rep in $(seq 1 200); do
         Rscript Teste.R $rho $rep
    done
done
```

In the terminal (after entering via ssh user@domain...):

```
chmod +x compoisson.sh
sh compoisson.sh &
exit
```

My `Teste.R` script (the content is not important, it could be an empty file):

```
rm(list=ls())
library(TMB)
# library(TMB, lib.loc = "/home/est/bonat/nobackup/github")
model <- "04_compoisson_bi" #1st try
compile(paste0(model, ".cpp"), flags = "-O0 -ggdb")
dyn.load(dynlib(model))
## Data simulation -------------------------------------------------------------
nresp <- 2; beta1 <- log(7);beta2 <- log(1.5);nu1 <- .7
nu2 <- .7;n <- 50;s2_1 <- 0.3;s2_2 <- 0.15;true_rho <- 0
sample_size <- 1000
openmp(4)
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
rhos <- c(-.5,0,.5)
true_rho <- rhos[abs(as.numeric(args[1]))]
j <- abs(as.numeric(args[2]))
seed <- 2109+j
res_neg <- simulacao(nresp, beta1, beta2, true_rho, s2_1, s2_2, seed, sample_size = sample_size, model, nu1=nu1, nu2=nu2, j = j) # 1 by time
saveRDS(res_neg, file = paste0(getwd(), "/Output/output_cmp_rho", true_rho, "n", sample_size, "j", j, ".rds"))
```

An important detail is that I need to run it on a external server via `ssh`.
I did a small test with an empty `.R` file on my PC, and I was able too see different processes being created via `htop`. On server, it did not happened.

I also tried `nohup` to run my `compoisson.sh` file ([question1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-processes-running-after-ssh-session-disconnects), [question2](https://superuser.com/questions/448445/run-bash-script-in-background-and-exit-terminal)), but I did not have any success. My test:

```
nohup compoisson.sh & 
ignoring the entrance and attaching the output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: failt to execute the command 'compoisson.sh': File or directory does not exists.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: to make processes continue even after closing the terminal, use `screen` mode

Comment: Try `nohup ./compoisson.sh &` in the directory where `compoisson.sh` is located, or give the absolute path of the `compoisson.sh`

Comment: Thank you @M.NejatAydin, it worked! What is the difference between these two methods? Thanks @Leonardo, I haven't tried `screen` because the other method worked

Comment: If the environment variable `PATH` doesn't contain the directory where `compoisson.sh` is located, you must give an absolute or relative path to run it. For example, if it is in the current directory, you can run it as `./compoisson.sh`; if it is in the directory `/xxx/yyy/zzz`, you can run it as  `/xxx/yyy/zzz/compoisson.sh`

Comment: Ok. I understood. But I was not clear on my question. What is the difference between `nohup compoisson.sh &` and `nohup ./compoisson.sh &`? Because if I remember well, I had tested on my PC and both worked (but on server, only `nohup ./compoisson.sh &` worked)

Comment: You've already got the answer. In your PC, the directory where `compoisson.sh` is located is in your `PATH`, but in the remote computer, it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `nohup ./compoisson.sh &` instead of `sh compoisson.sh &`